# mciSendString cannot save to directory path

Tags: c#, mcisendstring

VS C# 2008 SP1

I have a created a small application that records and plays audio. However, my application needs to save the wave file to the application data directory on the users computer.

The mciSendString takes a C style string as a parameter and has to be in 8.3 format. However, my problem is I can't get it to save. And what is strange is sometime it does and sometimes it doesn't. Howver, most of the time is failes. However, if I save directly to the C drive it works first time everything. I have used 3 different methods that I have coded below.

The error number that I get when it fails is 286."The file was not saved. Make sure your system has sufficient disk space or has an intact network connection"

Many thanks for any suggestins,

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern uint mciSendString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string command,
                                                 StringBuilder returnValue,
                                                 int returnLength,
                                                 IntPtr winHandle);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int mciGetErrorString(uint errorCode, StringBuilder errorText, int errorTextSize);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetShortPathName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string longPath,
                                                   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder shortPath,
                                                    int length);






 // Stop recording
        private void StopRecording()
        {
            // Save recorded voice
            string shortPath = this.shortPathName();
            string formatShortPath = string.Format("save recsound \"{0}\"", shortPath);
            uint result = 0;
            StringBuilder errorTest = new StringBuilder(256);

            // C:\DOCUME~1\Steve\APPLIC~1\Test.wav
            // Fails
            result = mciSendString(string.Format("{0}", formatShortPath), null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciGetErrorString(result, errorTest, errorTest.Length);

            // command line convention - fails 
            result = mciSendString("save recsound \"C:\\DOCUME~1\\Steve\\APPLIC~1\\Test.wav\"", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciGetErrorString(result, errorTest, errorTest.Length);         

            // 8.3 short format - fails
            result = mciSendString(@"save recsound C:\DOCUME~1\Steve\APPLIC~1\Test.wav", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciGetErrorString(result, errorTest, errorTest.Length);

            // Save to C drive works everytime.
            result = mciSendString(@"save recsound C:\Test.wav", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciGetErrorString(result, errorTest, errorTest.Length);

            mciSendString("close recsound ", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }


// Get the short path name so that the mciSendString can save the recorded wave file
        private string shortPathName()
        {
            string shortPath = string.Empty;
            long length = 0;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);

            // Get the length of the path 
            length = GetShortPathName(this.saveRecordingPath, buffer, 256);

            shortPath = buffer.ToString();

            return shortPath;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I test it in `C drive` and `D drive`, it works as long as the directory path does not contain space. `"C:\Test.wav"` and `"D:\mp3\test.wav"` both work, but `"D:\mp4 folder\test.wav"` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

[
string directoryString = "C:\DOCUME~1\Steve\APPLIC~1\";
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(directoryString);
mciSendString(@"save recsound Test.wav", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
mciSendString("close recsound ", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
]

Answer (score 0):

If the file path has spaces in it then use quotation marks around file name. In C# if you are using filePath as variable for file path then use following code:

```
msiSendString($"save recsound \"{filePath}\"", "", 0, 0)
```