# How to record WAV in c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, wav, audio-recording

I can get this code to work in a console application. But I want this to work on a Windows Forms application in c# visual studio 2010. 
Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

...

private void buttonRecordWAV_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("recording, press Enter to stop and save ...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("recording, press OK to stop recording and save", "Recording...", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("you entered the if statement");
                mciSendString("save recsound result.wav", "", 0, 0);
                mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
            }

    }
```

However, when I execute this, I don't see any 'result.wav' file in the bin/Debug folder. When I run this code on a console application, it works, and I can see a 'result.wav' in the bin/Debug folder and when I play that file, I hear what ever I recorded. 
Anybody know how to make this work in the C# Forms Application?
Thanks.

Comment: The `Window` class is WPF, not winforms..

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that it was called WPF

Comment: This question was asked previously, I'm using the same code. But it does not work in WPF applications. It only works in Console Applications.
[previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694274/how-do-i-record-audio-with-c-wpf)

Comment: WPF is a _visual presentation_ framework. It has very little to do with audio at all, and nothing with respect to _capturing_ audio. Did you see any actual errors or other anomalies running the code in a WPF program? Did you try executing the code in a different thread (e.g. one that's not an STA thread)? Are you sure the saved file didn't just wind up somewhere else? There might be subtle differences in the WPF environment that change, but don't completely disable the use of the MCI API from a WPF app.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I don't know what you mean by STA thread, or MCI API. I had no errors when i execute this, or the code from the answer suggested below. However, I cannot find recorded audio file saved anywhere in my system. I tried saving it in different locations and with different names. It is not saved. I don't even know if it is recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange mixture of technologies going on in your sample code. As you are using `Console.ReadLine` in an application that has a form as a front end. You are also using `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` which is a winforms class, not a WPF class, here you should be using `System.Windows.MessageBox`.

I just put a quick same together however using snippets from your example and it works for me. Sample as follows; markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="buttonRecordWav" Click="buttonRecordWav_Click">Start Recording</Button>
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind:

```
public enum MCIErrors
{
    NO_ERROR = 0,
    MCIERR_BASE = 256,
    MCIERR_INVALID_DEVICE_ID = 257,
    MCIERR_UNRECOGNIZED_KEYWORD = 259,
    MCIERR_UNRECOGNIZED_COMMAND = 261,
    MCIERR_HARDWARE = 262,
    MCIERR_INVALID_DEVICE_NAME = 263,
    MCIERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 264,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_OPEN = 265,
    MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER = 266,
    MCIERR_MISSING_COMMAND_STRING = 267,
    MCIERR_PARAM_OVERFLOW = 268,
    MCIERR_MISSING_STRING_ARGUMENT = 269,
    MCIERR_BAD_INTEGER = 270,
    MCIERR_PARSER_INTERNAL = 271,
    MCIERR_DRIVER_INTERNAL = 272,
    MCIERR_MISSING_PARAMETER = 273,
    MCIERR_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION = 274,
    MCIERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 275,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_NOT_READY = 276,
    MCIERR_INTERNAL = 277,
    MCIERR_DRIVER = 278,
    MCIERR_CANNOT_USE_ALL = 279,
    MCIERR_MULTIPLE = 280,
    MCIERR_EXTENSION_NOT_FOUND = 281,
    MCIERR_OUTOFRANGE = 282,
    MCIERR_FLAGS_NOT_COMPATIBLE = 283,
    MCIERR_FILE_NOT_SAVED = 286,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_TYPE_REQUIRED = 287,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_LOCKED = 288,
    MCIERR_DUPLICATE_ALIAS = 289,
    MCIERR_BAD_CONSTANT = 290,
    MCIERR_MUST_USE_SHAREABLE = 291,
    MCIERR_MISSING_DEVICE_NAME = 292,
    MCIERR_BAD_TIME_FORMAT = 293,
    MCIERR_NO_CLOSING_QUOTE = 294,
    MCIERR_DUPLICATE_FLAGS = 295,
    MCIERR_INVALID_FILE = 296,
    MCIERR_NULL_PARAMETER_BLOCK = 297,
    MCIERR_UNNAMED_RESOURCE = 298,
    MCIERR_NEW_REQUIRES_ALIAS = 299,
    MCIERR_NOTIFY_ON_AUTO_OPEN = 300,
    MCIERR_NO_ELEMENT_ALLOWED = 301,
    MCIERR_NONAPPLICABLE_FUNCTION = 302,
    MCIERR_ILLEGAL_FOR_AUTO_OPEN = 303,
    MCIERR_FILENAME_REQUIRED = 304,
    MCIERR_EXTRA_CHARACTERS = 305,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_NOT_INSTALLED = 306,
    MCIERR_GET_CD = 307,
    MCIERR_SET_CD = 308,
    MCIERR_SET_DRIVE = 309,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_LENGTH = 310,
    MCIERR_DEVICE_ORD_LENGTH = 311,
    MCIERR_NO_INTEGER = 312,
    MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSINUSE = 320,
    MCIERR_WAVE_SETOUTPUTINUSE = 321,
    MCIERR_WAVE_INPUTSINUSE = 322,
    MCIERR_WAVE_SETINPUTINUSE = 323,
    MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTUNSPECIFIED = 324,
    MCIERR_WAVE_INPUTUNSPECIFIED = 325,
    MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSUNSUITABLE = 326,
    MCIERR_WAVE_SETOUTPUTUNSUITABLE = 327,
    MCIERR_WAVE_INPUTSUNSUITABLE = 328,
    MCIERR_WAVE_SETINPUTUNSUITABLE = 329,
    MCIERR_SEQ_DIV_INCOMPATIBLE = 336,
    MCIERR_SEQ_PORT_INUSE = 337,
    MCIERR_SEQ_PORT_NONEXISTENT = 338,
    MCIERR_SEQ_PORT_MAPNODEVICE = 339,
    MCIERR_SEQ_PORT_MISCERROR = 340,
    MCIERR_SEQ_TIMER = 341,
    MCIERR_SEQ_PORTUNSPECIFIED = 342,
    MCIERR_SEQ_NOMIDIPRESENT = 343,
    MCIERR_NO_WINDOW = 346,
    MCIERR_CREATEWINDOW = 347,
    MCIERR_FILE_READ = 348,
    MCIERR_FILE_WRITE = 349,
    MCIERR_CUSTOM_DRIVER_BASE = 512
};

[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

private bool _recording = false;

private void buttonRecordWav_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    MCIErrors result;
    if (!_recording)
    {
        result = (MCIErrors)mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        if (result != MCIErrors.NO_ERROR)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error code: " + result.ToString());
            return;
        }
        result = (MCIErrors)mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        if (result != MCIErrors.NO_ERROR)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error code: " + result.ToString());
            return;
        }
        buttonRecordWav.Content = "Stop Recording";
        _recording = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = (MCIErrors)mciSendString("save recsound result.wav", "", 0, 0);
        if (result != MCIErrors.NO_ERROR)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Error code: " + result.ToString());
             return;
        }
        result = (MCIErrors)mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
        if (result != MCIErrors.NO_ERROR)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error code: " + result.ToString());
            return;
        }
        buttonRecordWav.Content = "Start Recording";
        _recording = false;
    }                            
}
```

If I run that, I get the wav file created as expected. Documentation on the mciSendString method here:

[mciSendString function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried your code, no errors, but no file is saved. I cannot find the recorded audio file anywhere in my system. I tried saving with different names, different locations.

Comment: Odd, it works for me. I've edited the answer to add some basic error handling. Include that and see if you get any errors.

Comment: I get this error: MCIERR_FILENAME_REQUIRED in a message box after I click 'stop recording'

Comment: Ok, so for some reason it doesn't like the filename when running in a wpf app. I suggest you Google that error code to see if you can find anything. At least it is giving you an error to work with now.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148022/mcisendstring-cannot-save-to-directory-path. This seems to suggest that if the save directory has a space, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't comment on the accepted solution (no rep) but ppl's problem with the accepted solution is due to spaces in the file path.  to resolve, just pass the **full path** to mciSendString and **wrap it in quotes**, like:

```
string fullPath = @"c:\path with spaces\result.wav";
result = (MCIErrors)mciSendString("save recsound \"" + fullPath + "\"", "", 0, 0);
```